# ng build --prod ERROR from UglifyJs

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I used angular-cli create a project, and 
**ng build** is alright. Unexpectedly, when I use **ng build --prod** get the Error :

```
ERROR in vender.d6758a1e6b8a2151c741.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected character '`'
```

I google and find some solve way that change 
**"target": "es5"** in tsconfig.json file but the target is es5 by default. I have no idea is there problem in my code or using wrong setting.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1", 
    "primeng": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
     "underscore": "^1.8.3",
     "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.0",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0" 
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Webpack.prod.js change the configuration like this.

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      htmlLoader: {
        minimize: false // workaround for ng2
      }
    })
  ]
```

Comment: Could you make it as answer

Answer (score 0):

We lose ng build, ng serve and other angular cli commands once we ejects webpack.js from angular-cli by using ng eject. Therefore, I will recommend following approach
to fix Unexpected character '`' issue:

a. Update @angular/cli to 1.5-rc.0 version in package.json: It has fix for Unexpected token '`'  issue

b. Update tsconfig.json to point to es2015 dependencies:
   "target": "es2015",
     "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]

This is a working fix.

Refer: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7756

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and indeed, to fix this error, simply add the workaround in the production.js file, given by @Vignesh :

```
  htmlLoader: {
      minimize: false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after doing many hours of research on this issue, we finally traced out.

First simple install "uglify-js".

> > npm install uglify-js -g

If this does not solve the this, In `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` /uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/blob/v0.4.6/src/index.js#L90).

Instead of `ast = compress.compress(ast);` that line should be

`ast = ast.transform(compress);`

In most of the cases if the above does not work, then the angular version needs to be upgraded to the latest and you have to copy all the project files to the newly created folder. This will work without fail and will save lot of your valuable hours in researching.